# Error in "Where Clause" in Esper Dataflows

Tags: java, dataflow, complex-event-processing, esper

Im trying to do some tests with Esper Dataflows, so i'm writing some patterns using the Select operator provided by Esper Dataflows. But I not getting it to work. There is a code for that i'm trying to do:

```
    public class BenchmarkEvent {
    long ReceivedTimestamp;
    long ProcessedTimestamp;

    String atr1;
    String atr2;
    String atr3;

    String getAtr1() {
        return atr1;
    }

}
```

Then, the sentence i'm trying to compile:

```
 "Select(demostream) -> outdemostream {"
                + "     select: (select * from demostream"
                + "              where demostream.atr1 = \"Attribute\") }" +
```

And finally, the error I get:

```
Failed to obtain operator 'Select': Error validating expression: Failed to validate filter expression 'demostream.getAtr1="Attribute"': Failed to resolve property 'demostream.getAtr1' to a stream or nested property in a stream
```

There is a way to make it work? Thanks in advance

Best regards,
Ivan

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. The event type name can usually be used for prefixing property names but it seems the compiler doesn't allow it for the data flow operator.
There is no need to use a prefix in the first place.

```
select * from demostream where atr1 = \"Attribute\"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :D

I tried as you said, but there is another error

Failed to validate filter expression 'atr1="Attribute"': Property named 'atr1' is not valid in any stream